# Database Scheme for Stores and Restaurants

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I am creating a database to hold both restaurants and stores. I am having some problems in deciding if I should have two tables, Restaurants & Stores, or only one, Businesses. With the Business approach I would have:

```
create table dbo.Businesses (
  Id int identity not null primary key clustered (Id),            
  BusinessTypeId int not null,
  Address nvarchar (200) not null,   
  City nvarchar (100) not null,       
  Name nvarchar (100) not null,
  AverageMealPrice int null
  -- Other business columns  
)

create table dbo.BusinessTypes (
  Id int identity not null primary key clustered (Id),      
  Name nvarchar (100) null
)
```

BusinessTypes can be Restaurant or Store ... Business table has a BusinessTypeId to classify that type of Business.

I have 2 problems:

1. Some columns are specific to certain kind of business while other are common.
2. There might be cases where a business can be either a Store or a Restaurant.

What scheme would you use? Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: What other tables do these tables join to? some kind of transactions? If a business can be a store or a restaurant, then it would seem they should go in the same table. Otherwise you'll need to record a single business in two tables.

Comment: I don't know what will you be storing, but if your database should contain all of the business products, then AverageMealPrice column is useless and you can query it with Max() function. This question is pretty broad, please provide more specific columns for certain kind of businesses.

Comment: howmany fields are specific to restaurant and howmany to stores ? If only a few columns than on table is ok. The types must have 3 values: "Restaurant", "Store", "Both" and than you can handle anything

Comment: @Hynek Bernard: In this case I don't have a Products table for stores or for restaurants. I am only saving some general information about them such as: Schedule, Location, AverageMealPrice (in case of restaurants) since for Stores it is not needed, HasDelivery (for both) ... Nothing to complex.

Comment: @GuidoG I have around 3 fields specific to a Store and 3 to a Restaurant ... Should I have those 3 types or have a many to many relationship between BusinessType and Business?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I do not have any Transactions or Products table ... Only global information about each Business just like Yellow Pages but a few are specific for Restaurants and other for Stores.

Answer (score 0):

Problem nr 1 is not that great problem. When You will store all in one table, You can have common columns and columns used only by one type - the other type will have null values there.

> There might be cases where a business can be either a Store or a
>   Restaurant.

This is problematic. It depends on the operations You will be doing on such an object being shop/restaurant at once, cause stored in one row it will loose it's individuality. You will not be able to refer to store or to restaurant separately, but to object that is both restaurant and shop. It can create many complications, depends on operations You will be performing on restaurants/objects.

Comment: For problem 2 I am considering to have a Many to Many relationship between Business and BusinessType and then if a Business is both a Store and a Restaurant I can associate that Business to both ... It also allows to add, in the future, other Business types.

Answer (score 0):

Having all in one table is much easier for searching through restaurants and stores.
If there are many fields that are specific for restaurant and for store you could create a Restaurant and a Store table with only these specific fields and keep a RestaurantID and e StoreID in the Bussiness table. In the bussiness table you than only keep common fields.

Also you can have 3 types in your types table :
Restaurant
Store
Both